# Android listview unfortunately, app has stopped

Tags: android, listview

I have an issue about listview filled with string item althouh I look up a search about it. I don't undertand where the problems comes from though I define layout.xml correctly. How can I solve it out?

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity {


    ArrayList<String> items= null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a);

        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        items.add("AAAA");
        items.add("BBB");
        items.add("CCC");
        items.add("DDD");


        ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);


        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewAttactivePlaces);

        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

    }
```

a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listviewAttactivePlaces"
    tools:context="com.example.android.turkeytourguide.AttactivePlacesActivity">

</ListView>
```

Comment: You need to create the object of the ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String> (); inside the onCreate method

Answer (score 1):

you have to declare your arrayList as follows

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

please add this..

```
items=new ArrayList<String>();


items.add("AAAA");
    items.add("BBB");
    items.add("CCC");
    items.add("DDD");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type in declaration

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity {


List<String> items= null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a);

    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    items.add("AAAA");
    items.add("BBB");
    items.add("CCC");
    items.add("DDD");


    ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);


    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewAttactivePlaces);

    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

}
```